# Script to create specified Tmux Panes

Tags: shell, tmux, tmuxinator

I want to create a script where number of panes (upto 16 panes) should be taken as input and create that many panes in a tmux session. Before I was hard-coding, using series of split-window cmds, however, now we want the script to be more generic. how can we achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`tmuxp` is a great tool for doing the above task.

https://github.com/tmux-python/tmuxp